# How do I use the DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am new to MVC and am trying to populate a DropDownList in my view with a list of 'rules' from my controller.  When I do it the way listed, I just get a dropdownlist with a bunch of items that say CellularAutomata.Models.Rules.  I know I am doing this incorrectly, I'm just wondering how I actually get it to show the rule description for each rule in the dropdownlist.

I have a Model

```
public class Rule
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }

    public Rule(int name, string description)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;

    }
    public Rule()
    {
        Name = 0;
        Description = "";
    }
}
```

A Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var rules = from rule in db.Rules
                    select rule;

        return View(rules.ToList());
    }
```

And a view

```
@model IEnumerable<CellularAutomata.Models.Rule>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Test", new SelectList(Model))
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Carnotaurus - I am not sure if you are trying to be funny or not but a Repeater is an ASP.NET Web Forms control. This is MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedRuleId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Rule> Rules { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Rules = db.Rules
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model CellularAutomata.Models.MyViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedRuleId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Rules, "ID", "Description")
)
```

Comment: So there is really no good way to do this without using a viewmodel?

Comment: @Doug S., I don't know what is your definition of a *good way*, but in ASP.NET MVC the usage of a view model is considered as the most correct way. Even this `Rule` model shouldn't be used in the view and part of the view model. The proper way is to have a RuleViewModel which will be adapted to the specific requirements of the view. You could then use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to convert between your models (presumably EF) and the view models.

Comment: I am using EF, and when I try to implement this answer I get "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression".  I've done some searching around and it seems that EF doesn't support the .tostring method.  I can't seem to find a definitive work around for this. What is the best way to handle this error in your opinion?